# Posts adjust Size and location. CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am having an issue making an HTML page where I put posts of images of different sizes. Image width needs to be the same and height will be different. When the top post image is a smaller height I want the lower post image to move up to cover the blank space. You can better understand by looking at the below images:

**This is what I made**

(Check links of images please)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/An2ca.png

**This is what I want**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQzFH.png

I hope you can understand now.

My CSS code is below:

```
.posts{
    width:80%;
    max-width:951px;
    min-height:990px;
    border:0px solid black;
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.post{
    width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:0px solid green;
    vertical-align:text-top !important;
}
.post img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:290px;
    height:auto;    
    transition:all 1s ease;
    opacity:1.0;
}
.post img:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at a Jquery plugin like Masonry or Isotope.

Comment: Sorry i cant understand. What you are saying for.

Comment: Yep...another [**masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) solution

Comment: He means this: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ but I recommend you do your own CSS markup it's better practice unless you absolutely do not need any custom behavior outside what those JS libraries provide.

Comment: What we are saying is that you cannot achieve that layout using `float`...perhaps `flexbox` **might** help but there are javascript plugins that will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you look first at the basics of what Flexbox does for you by going here: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). That aside you can try to play around by setting your image holding classes to use display: flex. Fair warning, if you do care about cross browser functionality, make sure flex is supported for the audience you're trying to capture. You can look here: [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

There are JS Libraries as suggested by the community (see your comments) that will leverage such functionality for you. I also will say that while these libraries may be robust, they will work as long as they achieve the functionality you desire, so take time to explore [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to see if these provide a solution for you.

I also recently found a good read regarding Flex Box: 
[A Visual Guide to CSS3 Flexbox Properties](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) box that you may find interesting and hopefully useful as well :)

Otherwise let us know, we will try to continue to help you if you need more assistance.